# How to display a different User Interface within a Web App (different colors, logos and some views)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I think I have a bit of a unique situation that I need some advice with. I currently have a C# MVC web application that we are re-branding for a different demographic. Majority of the features will remain the same, but what will be different are the colors, graphics and the initial Index page displayed when a user logs in. I've researched using Area's within the web application but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.
The goal is to not have to duplicate the web application at this point, to load different stylesheets based on which version of the web application is being used and also share some of the base stylesheets, also most of the views will need to be shared. I'd like to reduce the amount of code duplication as much as possible.

Comment: in layout view in shared folder you can load the css based on demographics.. did you try doing that ? \

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this situation is as unique as you think and is a very old problem (remember MySpace pages? :P) but there are a few things to solve here.

The first is how you are going to change the colors and graphics. Changing the colors would be fairly simple by switching out the stylesheet. The problem you will have is that you are either going to have to duplicate the entire stylesheet (which will be a nightmare to maintain) or separate out the colors into their own stylesheet (which would be awkward for development). I would be tempted to combine the two methods by using a pre-processor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). These would allow you to define the colors as variables and use them throughout the other stylesheets. You would then compile the CSS twice, once with each set of colors. This gives you the best compromise of functionality (you can still minify), ease of development and ease of maintenance. SASS and LESS are very similar in feature sets. The choice of which to use usually comes down to develer preference or 3rd party library use.

For graphics, hopefully you have defined them in the stylesheets using `background` tags already. If not, I think it would be easiest to migrate to this strategy (assuming this is suitable for the images with regards to accessibility and functionality). It's going to be much easier this way than adding logic in lots of places to pick one image over another.

Finally for changing the index page when a user logs in, assuming you are selecting the page based on some user setting, I think the best course of action would be to either modify the redirect after login, or add a check on the home page to serve a different view. If you have links to the home page anywhere, the check on the home page action method will likely be the best approach as it will guarantee the correct page is served every time. If there is logic in the action method which populates the home page with data, it would probably be best to split the home pages into separate private methods:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("CustomisedTheme"))
    {
        return CustomisedIndex();
    }
    else
    {
        return DefaultIndex();
    }
}

private IActionResult CustomisedIndex()
{
    // Complex logic to populate view
    // ...

    return View("CustomisedIndex");
}

private IActionResult CustomisedIndex()
{
    // Complex logic to populate view
    // ...

    return View("CustomisedIndex");
}
```

Of course, this all assumes you are only using a few different styles. If you are looking into customizable styles (like having a self-serve customizing interface), it becomes a whole different problem which I'm not going to attempt to answer on Stack Overflow :)